# how to parse '+' in httpParam while post request in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working to validate the user token with the server token. I get the user token through URL i.e.
http://localhost:3200/#/abc/onboard?token=mk%20KShJsttRRl1NByG76pQ%3D%3D.

by getting token from URL I am getting '+' in URL.

By sending the token to verify through API I have to use httpParam to send the token to the server for verification.

but it fails because of '+' is not parse by httpParam.

```
let baseToken = decodeURIComponent((this.token + '').replace(/%20/g, "+"))

      const payload = new HttpParams()
        .set('token', baseToken)
```

```
validateUserToken(payload) {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'TOKEN': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

    return this.http.post(this.tokenValidateUrl, payload, { headers });
  }
```

please help and suggest to me how to do this, I am stuck here from last 1 day.

Comment: why do you want to replace %20 with a +?

Comment: I want to pass this token in API, so I can validate it

Comment: after decodeURIComponent there will be no %20 in token, you can try priting basetoken without replace.

Comment: i had solve my problem it's because of default behavior of HttpParam class in angular. refer link https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-angular-httpclient-not-escaping-url-parameters-ddce3f9b8746